# Scala error defining object

Tags: eclipse, scala, eof, scala-ide

I've been trying to get a Scala hello world example running on Eclipse using the Scala plugin. Writing the following:

```
package scala_test

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello, World") 
  }  
}
```

produces the following error:

```
<console>:1: error: eof expected but '}' found.
       }
       ^
```

I've tried this on both a Windows machine and a Mac (both were using Eclipse 3.7). I've tried commenting out the function definition (just leaving an empty body for the Test object) and the error still occurs. Any ideas as to what might cause this?

Comment: It works fine for me.  Maybe try cleaning the project (Project -> Clean)?

Comment: Tried that on both machines but still get the same error. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 8):

You need to see output in console, not in scala interpreter.
Just right click on scala file and select "run as scala application".

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added the Scala nature to the project.  On some versions of the plugin, that option is only available from the contextual "Configuration" menu if the Scala perspective is active.  Your project icon should have an "S" instead of a "J" in the corner if you have made this change.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure its in the right package, runs for me.  I'm using this plugin

http://scala-ide.org/

Comment: I just checked and the file is in the right package (i.e. the ScalaTest file is in the scala_test package). That's the same plugin I'm using as well... Was there any particular setup you had to do aside from installing the plugin through Eclipse to get it working?